# apache camel | jetty | Content-Type should be set on response if provided as OUT header

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

The Content-Type is not set in HttpBinding if an end-user has provided one as a OUT header.

So if an user exposes a Jetty service and lets requests fly in that is text/plain and want to return a response that is application/json or application/xml or the likes the content type can not be set as:
exchange.getOut().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Camel Version: 2.9.2
Camel Jetty Jar Version 2.9.0

Problem statement: Although I include the statement setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); or setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");, upon debugging I can see the following behaviour.

1.) Class "DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy", method "doFiltering" contains "Content-Type" as one of the filters to skip. Thus it removes the "Content-Type" from header if mentioned explicitly also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with Camel 2.9.4 as we have fixed a number of bugs since that release.

Comment: Thanks Clause for the reply. Problem to moving to 2.9.4 is that our complete application is based on 2.9.0 and right now, since Go Live date is coming near, we cannot afford to change it. Is there any tweak which can be made to get "Content-Tye" available in response header? Also, is Camel-Jetty 2.9.4 compatible with camel 2.9.0. Please help me out on the same as I an totally stuck with the problem.

Comment: See this FAQ about IN vs OUT - http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html